# Extracting 2 digit hour from POSIXct in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct, hour

I would like to extract the hour from a `POSIXct` time in R, but retrieve the 2 digit answer.

For example,

```
test=as.POSIXct("2015-03-02 03:15:00")
test
[1] "2015-01-02 03:15:00 GMT"
month(testing)
[1] 1
hour(testing)
[1] 3
```

The results give the relevant month and hour, but I would like to see `01` and `03` instead of just `1` and `3`.

Comment: `format(test, "%H")`, etc.  See `?strptime` for percent codes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
strftime(test, format="%H")
```

to extract hours and

```
strftime(test, format="%m")
```

for month